# Appending a dynamic column of data to multiple CSVs

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a script that downloads multiple CSVs all with similar names (i.e. data.csv, data(1).csv) and I want to append a column to every CSV and then combine them into one CSV.

So for example,

data.csv has 4 headers (header_1, header_2, etc) and I would like to add header_5 with the variable foobar. For data.csv, foobar is "duck" and so for every row that data.csv has, header_5 would have that many ducks.

data(1).csv is the same deal but this time variable foobar is now "dog". And the script would populate header_5 with however many dogs.

At the last step, the 2 CSVs would be combined -- retaining the modified data -- into one giant CSV.

I have been thinking about this for a long time. I don't know a lot about Ruby and this sort of problem is new to me so I hope I'm explaining it well.

I thought about first modifying the CSVs to have the new column of data and then combining them but I keep running into the problem of the names of the CSVs. In order for me to modify the files, I need to know the names so I thought of wildcards. But then how would I differentiate between the CSVs? It would probably overwrite the data.

My current code has that issue.

```
 def CSV_Creation (source)


        input_files = Dir.glob("data*.csv")

        all_headers = input_files.reduce([]) do |all_headers, file|
            header_line = File.open(file, &:gets)
            all_headers | CSV.parse_line(header_line)
        end


        CSV.open("out.csv", "a+") do |out|
            all_headers << "Source"
            out << all_headers 


            input_files.each do |file|
                CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
                    out << all_headers.map { |header| row[header] }



                end
            end
        end
    end
```

- The source parameter changes depending on which CSV is being downloaded
- I used wildcards to collect all of the CSVs, collected the headers in order to add another header, and dumped all of the data into a new CSV. But of course the data gets overwritten.

I am not entirely sure how I would keep the data in that last column from not being overwritten.

**EDIT**

Thank you for all of your replies thus far. I have updated code that will hopefully make more sense:

```
def CSV_Creation (source)



        l_source = {'lead_source' => "#{source}"}

        input_file = Dir.glob("data*.csv").last



        puts "Here is " + input_file


        rows = CSV.open(input_file, headers: true).map{ |row| row.to_h }


        rows.each { |h| h.merge!(l_source)}
        headers = rows.first.keys
       rows.first.keys.each {|k| puts k}



        csv_response = CSV.generate do |csv| 
            csv << headers
            rows.each do |row|
                csv << row.values_at(*headers) 
            end
        end
        File.open("#{source}.csv", "w") {|file| file.write(csv_response)}


    end
```

This creates two different csv files with the appropriate column and data. Now I just need to figure out how to combine the two files.

**SECOND EDIT**

This is what the final code looks like. It does what I ask so I figured it's alright?

```
 def CSV_Creation (source)



        l_source = {'lead_source' => "#{source}"}

        input_file = Dir.glob("data*.csv").last



        puts "Here is " + input_file


        rows = CSV.open(input_file, headers: true).map{ |row| row.to_h }


        rows.each { |h| h.merge!(l_source)}
        headers = rows.first.keys
       rows.first.keys.each {|k| puts k}



        csv_response = CSV.generate do |csv| 
            csv << headers
            rows.each do |row|
                csv << row.values_at(*headers) 
            end
        end
        File.open("#{source}.csv", "w") {|file| file.write(csv_response)}


        input_files = Dir.glob("#{source}*.csv")


        all_headers = input_files.reduce([]) do |all_headers, file|
            header_line = File.open(file, &:gets)
            all_headers | CSV.parse_line(header_line)
        end

        CSV.open("out.csv", "a+") do |out|
            out << all_headers 

            input_files.each do |file|
                CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
                    out << all_headers.map { |header| row[header] }
                end
            end
        end







    end
```

Big thanks to everyone who gave me advice!!

Comment: If there are `n` CSV files. in the end do you want `n` modified CSV files and one combined CSV file, or just the one combined file?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The way that it has been done is that there are two modified CSV files that will be combined into just one file. Thank you for your inquiry.

Comment: Herbert, I didn't notice your comment before posting my answer. However, you said, "I want to append a column to every CSV and then combine them into one CSV." That does not indicate that a column has already been added to each of the files that are to be combined. If the columns have already been added my answer can be simplified quite a bit. I will leave that to you as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I have a dumb way to do what you ask :

- Join the lines of each csv file in the out.csv file (with a little security)
- Tell which from file a colunm comes in source.csv

```rb
# idk what to do with source
def CSV_Creation (source)
    input_files = Dir.glob("data*.csv").map { |filename| File.open(filename) }

    headers = input_files.map(&:gets)
    # Fix for "empty" lines in data files
    line_fix = headers.map { |header| CSV.parse_line(header).map { ',' }.join }

    CSV.open("out.csv", "a+") do |out|
        # We add the header
        out.puts headers.map(&:chomp).join(',')
        # We try to read all the lines
        until (lines = input_files.map(&:gets)).concat.empty?
            out.puts lines.map.with_index do |line, index|
                line&.chomp || line_fix[index]
            end.join(',')
        end
    end

    # In order to know the names we'll store a csv associating header to the filename
    File.open('source.csv', 'w') do |f|
        f.puts headers.map(&:chomp).join(',')
        line = input_files.map.with_index do |file, index|
            ([file.path] * line_fix[index].size).to_csv
        end
        f.puts line.map(&:chomp).join(',')
    end
ensure
    input_files.each(&:close)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As the header rows are to effectively be treated like all another rows, there is significant advantage to using methods of the class [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to perform this task. (Note: I posted this answer before preparing a second answer that employs CSV methods. Even though I prefer my other answer I have chosen to leave this one.)

**Code**

```
def combine_csv_files(*csv_files, sep, out_file_name)
  IO.write(out_file_name,
    csv_files.each_with_object([]) do |(file_name, new_header_name), arr|
      a = IO.readlines(file_name, chomp: true)
      arr.concat(
        a.map { |line| line.split(sep) }.
          transpose << [new_header_name, *(1..a.size-1).to_a]
      )
    end.transpose.
        map { |a| a.join(sep) }.
        join("\n")
  )
end
```

**Example**

Let's first create two CSV files<sup>1</sup>.

```
str =<<-DA_END
dog,cat
woof,purr
devoted,independent
DA_END

FNAME1 = 'dogsandcats.csv'
IO.write(FNAME1, str)
  #=> 38
```

```
str =<<-DA_END
cow,pig
moo,oink
dumb,smart
DA_END

FNAME2 = 'cowsandpigs.csv'
IO.write(FNAME2, str)
  #=> 28
```

Suppose we wish to add columns to these two files with headers `"col1"` and `"col2"`, respectively. Then

```
combine_csv_files(*[[FNAME1, "col1"], [FNAME2, "col2"]], ',', 'everything.csv') 

puts IO.read('everything.csv')
dog,cat,col1,cow,pig,col2
woof,purr,1,moo,oink,1
devoted,independent,2,dumb,smart,2
```

**Explanation**

We can step through the calculations. Suppose

```
csv_files = [[FNAME1, "col1"], [FNAME2, "col2"]]
sep = ','
out_file_name = 'everything.csv'
```

The first step is to create an enumerator.

```
enum = csv_files.each_with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["dogsandcats.csv", "col1"], ["cowsandpigs.csv", "col2"]]:
      # each_with_object([])>
```

See [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)<sup>2</sup>. This creates an enumerator. The method [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html) is used to generate elements by the enumerator, which are passed to the block and assigned to the block variables.

```
(file_name, new_header_name), arr = enum.next
  #=> [["dogsandcats.csv", "col1"], []] 
file_name
  #=> "dogsandcats.csv" 
new_header_name
  #=> "col1" 
arr
  #=> []
```

The process of dividing the element returned by `enum.next` into components that are assigned to block variables is called [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). We now perform the block calculation.

```
b = IO.readlines(file_name, chomp: true)
  #=> ["dog,cat", "woof,purr", "devoted,independent"]
c = b.map { |line| line.split(sep) }
  #=> [["dog", "cat"], ["woof", "purr"], ["devoted", "independent"]] 
d = c.transpose
  #=> [["dog", "woof", "devoted"], ["cat", "purr", "independent"]] 
e = d << [new_header_name, *(1..b.size-1).to_a] 
  #=> [["dog", "woof", "devoted"], ["cat", "purr", "independent"], ["col1", 1, 2]]
```

See [IO::readlines](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-readlines) <sup>3</sup>, [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose). Continuing with the block calculation,

```
arr.concat(e)
  #=> [["dog", "woof", "devoted"], ["cat", "purr", "independent"], ["col1", 1, 2]]
```

See [Array#concat](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-concat). The enumerator now generates a second element, which is passed to the block, the block variables are assigned values and the block calculation is performed.

```
(file_name, new_header_name), arr = enum.next
  #=> [["cowsandpigs.csv", "col2"], []] 
file_name
  #=> "cowsandpigs.csv" 
new_header_name
  #=> "col2" 
arr
  #=> [["dog", "woof", "devoted"], ["cat", "purr", "independent"], ["col1", 1, 2]]
```

Notice that `arr` has been updated.

```
b = IO.readlines(file_name, chomp: true)
  #=> ["cow,pig", "moo,oink", "dumb,smart"] 
c = b.map { |line| line.split(sep) }
  #=> [["cow", "pig"], ["moo", "oink"], ["dumb", "smart"]] 
d = c.transpose
  #=> [["cow", "moo", "dumb"], ["pig", "oink", "smart"]] 
e = d << [new_header_name, *(1..b.size-1).to_a] 
  #=> [["cow", "moo", "dumb"], ["pig", "oink", "smart"], ["col2", 1, 2]] 
arr.concat(e)
  #=> [["dog",  "woof", "devoted"    ],
  #    ["cat",  "purr", "independent"],
  #    ["col1", 1,      2],
  #    ["cow",  "moo",  "dumb"       ],
  #    ["pig",  "oink", "smart"      ],
  #    ["col2", 1,      2            ]]
```

Now `enum` attempts to generate another element.

```
enum.next
  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

This exception causes `arr` to be returned. Continuing,

```
f = arr.transpose
  #=> [["dog",     "cat",         "col1", "cow",  "pig",   "col2"],
  #    ["woof",    "purr",        1,      "moo",  "oink",  1     ],
  #    ["devoted", "independent", 2,      "dumb", "smart", 2]    ] 
g = f.map { |a| a.join(',') }
  #=> ["dog,cat,col1,cow,pig,col2",
  #    "woof,purr,1,moo,oink,1",
  #    "devoted,independent,2,dumb,smart,2"] 
h = g.join("\n")
  #=> "dog,cat,col1,cow,pig,col2\nwoof,purr,1,moo,oink,1\ndevoted,independent,2,dumb,smart,2" 
IO.write(out_file_name, h)
  #=> 83
```

See [IO::write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-write).

Let's confirm we obtained the desired result.

```
puts IO.read(out_file_name)
dog,cat,col1,cow,pig,col2
woof,purr,1,moo,oink,1
devoted,independent,2,dumb,smart,2
```

See [IO::read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-read).

<sup>1. Note that the following two heredocs have been indented 4 spaces. If one wishes to run this code they should be unindented first.</sup>

<sup>2. The pound sign in `Enumerable#each_with_object` indicates that `each_with_object` is an instance method. By constrast, the double-colon in `IO::readlines` indicates that `readlines` is a (class) method of the class `IO`.</sup>

<sup>3. `IO` methods and instance methods are often written with `File`, rather than `IO`, as the receiver (e.g., `File.write(fname)`). That is allowed because `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File.superclass #=> IO`) and therefore inherits its method and instance methods.</sup>

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much for taking the time out of your day for this!

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
require 'csv'

def combine_csv_files(*csv_files, sep, out_file_name)
  (file_name, new_header_name), *rest = csv_files
  csv = CSV.read(file_name, headers: true, col_sep: sep)
  new_col = (1..csv.size).to_a
  csv[new_header_name] = new_col
  rest.each do |file_name, new_header_name|
    csv1 = CSV.read(file_name, headers: true, col_sep: sep)
    csv1.headers.each { |header| csv1.each { |row| csv[header] = row[header] } }
    csv[new_header_name] = new_col
  end
  CSV.open(out_file_name, "w") do |f|
    f << csv.headers
    csv.each { |row| f << row }
  end
end
```

**Example**

Suppose we have files

```
FNAME1 = 'dogsandcats.csv'
FNAME2 = 'cowsandpigs.csv'
```

whose contents are as given in my other answer, and we wish to add columns to those two files with headers `"col1"` and `"col2"`, respectively, and combine those two files.

```
combine_csv_files(*[[FNAME1, "col1"], [FNAME2, "col2"]], ',', 'everything.csv') 

puts IO.read('everything.csv')
dog,cat,col1,cow,pig,col2
woof,purr,1,moo,oink,1
devoted,independent,2,dumb,smart,2
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows (for `FNAME1` and `FNAME2` as defined for the example).

```
csv_files = [[FNAME1, "col1"], [FNAME2, "col2"]]
sep = ','
out_file_name = 'everything.csv'
```

Split `csv_files` between its first element and all remaining elements.

```
(file_name, new_header_name), *rest = csv_files
  #=> [["dogsandcats.csv", "col1"], ["cowsandpigs.csv", "col2"]]
file_name
  #=> "dogsandcats.csv"
new_header_name
  #=> "col1"
rest
  #=> [["cowsandpigs.csv", "col2"]]
```

The process of dividing `csv_files` in this way is called [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). Now read the first file, creating a `CSV` object.

```
csv = CSV.read(file_name, headers: true, col_sep: sep)
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

Let's see what we have.

```
csv.to_a
  #=> [["dog", "cat"], ["woof", "purr"], ["devoted", "independent"]]
```

Now add a column and see what we then have.

```
new_col = (1..csv.size).to_a 
csv[new_header_name] = new_col
  #=> [1, 2] 
csv.to_a
  #=> [["dog", "cat", "col1"], ["woof", "purr", 1], ["devoted", "independent", 2]]
```

Read the descriptor for the next CSV file, then read the file into a `CSV` object `csv1`:

```
file_name, new_header_name = rest.shift
  #=> ["cowsandpigs.csv", "col2"] 
csv1 = CSV.read(file_name, headers: true, col_sep: sep)
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
csv1.to_a
  #=> [["cow", "pig"], ["moo", "oink"], ["dumb", "smart"]]
```

Append `csv1` to `csv`:

```
csv1.headers.each { |header| csv[header] = csv1.map { |row| row[header] } }
  #=> ["cow", "pig"]
csv.to_a
  #=> [["dog",     "cat",         "col1", "cow",  "pig"  ],
  #    ["woof",    "purr",        1,      "moo",  "oink" ],
  #    ["devoted", "independent", 2,      "dumb", "smart"]]
```

Add the new column and examing `csv`:

```
csv[new_header_name] = new_col
  #=> [1, 2]
csv.to_a
  #=> [["dog",     "cat",         "col1", "cow",  "pig",   "col2"],
  #    ["woof",    "purr",        1,      "moo",  "oink",  1     ],
  #    ["devoted", "independent", 2,      "dumb", "smart", 2     ]]
```

All that remains is to write `csv` to file.

```
CSV.open(out_file_name, "w") do |f|
  f << csv.headers
  csv.each { |row| f << row }
end
  #> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

Let's look at the contents of the file just written:

```
puts IO.read(out_file_name)
dog,cat,col1,cow,pig,col2
woof,purr,1,moo,oink,1
devoted,independent,2,dumb,smart,2
```